# how to run eclipse by using a specified java path directory in eclipse not by the default Java path

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to set java path to a specified java directory in eclipse, not the default installed java path. I want to run eclipse by using java from my specified path. But all the time eclipse runs by using the default installed java path. I have specified the Path in the "eclipse.ini" file but this path is not used by eclipse to run.. Please hep me...
This is my "eclipse.ini" file

-startup

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar

--launcher.library

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807

-product

com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct

-showsplash

org.eclipse.platform

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

256m

--launcher.defaultAction

openFile

-vm

/home/bibin/Documents/ADTBUNDLE/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/java

-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

-Xms512m

-Xmx1024m

Comment: Show us the eclipse.ini you are using.

Comment: hi thanks for the coment, This is my eclipse.ini file

Comment: Edit the question rather than trying to put things in a comment.

Comment: Put that in the question, it is important to see where the line breaks are.

Comment: I have set the path and run the eclipse it runs fine but it uses the java path which i have installed. not the path specified in "eclipse.ini file"

Comment: Do you mean Eclipse itself is using some other path or that when you run other programs from Eclipse it uses a different Java?

Comment: I want run it on ubuntu, this path is not taking for running eclipse. When eclipse runs it uses the installed java path not this path. How ican be solve this? please comment..

Comment: @greg-449 : yes ... when running eclipse it uses another java path.. that is the path which i have installed java.

Comment: @greg-449: hello there.. u got my problem?

Comment: I'd bet that the JVM required by the -vm parameter is the javaw.

Comment: @LittleSanti: but i give javaws file but it shows error. i am using jdk1.6

Comment: Where are you looking to see what Eclipse is running? Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Configuration is the correct place to look.

Comment: @greg-449: Thanks for ur comment.. please do comment..I am using Eclipse Juno, When i start eclipse with the above eclipse.ini file where i have mentioned the java path which eclipse should take, but after starting eclipse i just goto Window->preference->java->installed JRE: It shows another java path(this path is the location where i have installed java, this is an openjdk1.6) but  iwnt to eclipse should take the java specified in eclipse.ini file

Comment: Installed JREs is **not** the JRE that Eclipse is running. It is the JRE it will use when you run a Java program from Eclipse. Use the Add button to add new ones.

Comment: @greg-449: Again thanks.. My intention is to use both eclipse and java together a bundle(meaning a zip file) to use by others.. so when the eclipse is copied in other machines it should take the java provided in the bundle. so i would set the java path as relative path in eclipse.ini file.  I wish to run eclipse by using the given path in all ubuntu machines not using the default installed java. and it sholud not be manually added. When eclipse starts it should automatically select the specified java path in "eclipse.ini" file

Comment: @greg-449: I have set the jaav path in eclipse.ini file is "/home/bibin/Documents/ADTBUNDLE/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/java"  but when i starts eclipse and  i just goto Window->preference->java->installed JRE:  java path is " usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386"

Answer (score 0):

@Bibin Jose I think you're confused, The eclipse.ini is a file where the eclipse configuration to start is. In "Windows>>preference>>java>>installed JRE" is where you can set which JRE you want to compile you project. You can add a lot of JRE in preference.
If you want, click in "Add" button, choice "Standar VM" and click in next button, finally set the path where your other jdk is installed.